# 20.10 HP Obelisk 875 Desktop w/ Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Locks Randomly

Tags: nvidia, 20.10

My desktop randomly locks up -- I have investigated multiple forum posts and have not identified the cause or a solution so I'm hoping that someone has had a similar experience. When the system locks, it will either black out all 4 monitors or will freeze the screens. Audio will continue playing for approximately one minute after it locks and then the audio stops as well. The only remedy is a hard reset using the power button. There doesn't seem to be a pattern as to when it locks - I've had it lock while sitting idle or while under heavy use.

See the posts below for as many details as I can think to provide to get started:

HP Obelisk 875
Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080

lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a40fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a20fffff [size=289M]
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at a4500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at a4516000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at a451f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a2100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a2101000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143
    Memory at a451c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at a4514000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a451b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 6050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 6040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 6020 [size=32]
    Memory at a451a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a4400000-a44fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a4300000-a43fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: a4200000-a42fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at a2102000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 144
    Memory at a4510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146
    Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Physical Resizable BAR
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU104 HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a4080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at a2040000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at a4084000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia-gpu
    Kernel modules: i2c_nvidia_gpu

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at a4404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a4400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac 2 × 2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth 4.2 Combo Adapter (MU-MIMO supported)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 145
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a4300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-b8-22-01
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822be
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be

04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at a4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=32 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [260] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

uname -a

```
Linux shannon-OMEN-by-HP-Obelisk-Desktop-875-0xxx 5.8.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 12:42:13 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 28672  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
rc_cec                 16384  0
typec_displayport      16384  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    77824  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_sof               122880  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_soc_core          278528  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               20480  0
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  8
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
nouveau              2043904  20
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_usb_audio         286720  5
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
rtw88_8822be           16384  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
rtw88_8822b           225280  1 rtw88_8822be
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
rtw88_pci              24576  1 rtw88_8822be
rtw88_core            172032  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8822b
snd_pcm               118784  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
rapl                   20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_cstate           20480  0
mac80211              917504  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ttm                   102400  1 nouveau
uvcvideo               98304  0
btusb                  57344  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                28672  1 btusb
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cfg80211              782336  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
hp_wmi                 20480  0
drm_kms_helper        225280  1 nouveau
bluetooth             602112  34 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
serio_raw              20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
videodev              245760  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
rc_core                53248  3 rc_cec,cec
efi_pstore             16384  0
ucsi_ccg               20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
snd                    94208  30 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  1
typec_ucsi             32768  1 ucsi_ccg
ee1004                 20480  0
8250_dw                16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 28672  0
mc                     57344  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
mei                   110592  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
typec                  53248  2 typec_displayport,typec_ucsi
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
acpi_tad               20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   565248  8 drm_kms_helper,ttm,nouveau
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               45056  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     45056  0
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  2 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   135168  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
psmouse               159744  0
nvme                   45056  2
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
nvme_core             110592  4 nvme
r8169                  94208  0
ahci                   40960  1
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
idma64                 20480  0
xhci_pci               20480  0
realtek                24576  1
libahci                36864  1 ahci
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
wmi                    32768  4 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  1 nouveau
pinctrl_cannonlake     36864  0
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlake
```

Comment: Random locks 99% of the time it is the memory modules. So please check those from a live session.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to a crashed application or service? Perhaps a hung process that was killed? 

Comment: I don't see anything in syslog...  As for the memory modules could you give me some guidance on how to check those?